# Kali Linux internet connection

Tags: wifi, internet, kali-linux

I've installed KaliLinux on my VirtualBox. Then I faced a problem: I couldn't connect to the internet. I was going through many tutorials, that's what I did: `-Went to Settings->Network`, enabled network adapter, changed it to `"Bridged Adapter"` and made it `"AllowAll"`. Didn't help. `Airmon-ng` shows empty result set. Next thing is that `"ifconfig"/"iwconfig"` shows `Eth0` for me, while ppl showing tutorials had Wlan0 there. On my notebook I'm using wifi, no cables or anything. Furthermore, on `Devices->UsbDevices`, I have my mouse device detected + "Unknown Device" clicking on which causes an error.

## edit

I'd forget: I also change the boolean in NetworkManager.conf file to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings > Network > NAT, Check Cable Connected.

Advanced > Adapter Type > 82540EM > Promiscuous Mode > Deny

In the VM, enable dhcpcd

[image: VirtualBox Network Settings - Windows Host]

Comment: Can't switch to "Deny" when NAT is chosen

Comment: @user3447603 See Screenshot, Deny Should be the default setting, and is grayed out.

Comment: Well, I switched to AllowAll trying all the stuff around. So I went for Bridged again, switched to Deny, then changed to NAT again. Now it's grayed with Deny, haha. I finally have a connection, thank you. Could you suggest me how could I obtain a different IP? Like this VM was a separate machine

Comment: This Setting should give you an IP, but if you want a different one, edit the configs in the Virtual Machine to the settings you desire.

Comment: The IP i'm getting is some internal one. I mean I can't even use a tool like Wireshark to get traffic from host notebook.

Comment: I can't help there.  The issue here is: You cannot use Bridged Adapter as the VM only emulates wired adapters.  In this way your wireless adapter is a "passthrough device." The emulated adapter is riding on top of your wireless adapter as a TUN/TAP.  As such, you get an emulated IP Address.  You could try Bridged Adapter but if that doesn't work, all you can do is configure DHCP in the machine to be on the same network you're trying to monitor.

Comment: That all sounds nice and I'm pretty sure it's possible what you're suggesting. The problem is I'm super-beginner, it's my first try in that all. I barely know what DHCP is, configuring this is a bit too much for me atm. Anyways, I really appreciate your help and time spent on this :)

Comment: See [this tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/DHCP-Server.html) and [this Wiki on DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol).  I can't tell you how to configure your client until you tell me what DHCP Client Kali uses.

Answer (score 2):

I found the instructions in the following link and it worked for me, since I already had the setup described by eyeyoung100 :

[Can't access internet in kali virtualbox](https://superuser.com/questions/678893/cant-access-internet-in-kali-virtualbox)

Essentially the commands that got me online were

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up 
sudo dhclient eth0
```

Although in my case it was `eth1`, since `eth0` was already connected to the host-only network.